# Input loses focus when I type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Anytime I type the input loses focus. The root cause of problem, I think, is the submit button because I noticed If I use a normal button component, it works, but I want to implement the button this way. How do I fix bug/issue please?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { Input } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const Login = () => {

const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const { email, password } = formData;

const onChange = (e) => {
setFormData((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
}));
  };
  
  function SubmitButton() {
    if (email && password.length > 7) {
      return (
        <Button
          type="submit"
          isLoading={isLoading}
        >
          Login to your account
        </Button>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Button
          type="submit"
          isDisabled
        >
          Login to your account
        </Button>
      );
    }
  }
  
  return (
               <div>
                <Input
                  name="email"
                  value={email}
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
   
                  <Input
                    value={password}
                    name="password"
                    onChange={onChange}
                  />
                  
                  <SubmitButton />
                 </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used chakra but giving this a try. Ran the following code to simulate a user logging in and didn't notice any issues with focus that you mention. Make sure you import all necessary components.

Note: check the console for output

```
**Login.jsx** 

import React, { useState } from "react"; 
import { Button, Input, FormControl } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { userLogin } from "../utils/mockAPI"; 

export default function Login() {
  // useState
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); 

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: "", 
    password: "", 
  }); 

  // destructure email/password from formData 
  const { email, password } = formData; 

  // handleChange 
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState, 
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value, 
    })); 
  };

  // handleSubmit 
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    console.log("Submitting"); 
    setIsLoading(true); 
    try {
      await userLogin({ email, password }); 
      setIsLoading(false); 
      // do other stuff like navigating back to home or something... 
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false); 
      setFormData({
        email: "", 
        password: "", 
      }); 
    };
  };

  const SubmitButton = () => {
    if(email && password.length > 7) {
      return (
        <Button
          variant="outline"
          type="submit"
          mt={4}
          isLoading={isLoading}
          loadingText="Submitting"
        >
          Login to your account
        </Button>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <Button
        variant="outline"
        type="submit"
        isDisabled
        mt={4}
        >Login to your account</Button>
      )
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <FormControl isRequired>
        <Input 
          name="email"
          type="email"
          placeholder="Enter email"
          value={email}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl isRequired>
        <Input 
          name="password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Enter password"
          value={password}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </FormControl>
      <SubmitButton />
      </form>
  )
}

**mockAPI.js** 

export const userLogin = async ({ email, password }) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(email === "test@test.com" && password === "password") {
        resolve() 
        console.log("Welcome user!")
      } else {
        reject() 
        console.log("Incorrect username or password")
      }
    }, 3000); 
  })
}
```